# Magento - Hide a delivery method if order total less than n?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I have two delivery methods, Flat Rate 1 and Flat Rate 2.

I want to hide Flat Rate 1 if the order total is less than $15.00.

How can this be done in Magento?

Comment: It looks like this question is similar, if you're open to writing your own shipping method: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/59087/set-minimum-order-price-for-a-shipping-method

Comment: @Mike, seems excessive for what I need, but if there is no other way I'll do that.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in the template. You can add a condition in  app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml

Hope this helps.

regards, David

Answer (score 1):

Hacky, but here's how I did it.

In the following files...

- template/msp_flatshipping5/available.phtml
- template/checkout/multishipping/shipping.phtml
- template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml

...insert this after `foreach ($_shippingRateGroups as $code => $_rates):`

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
if($code == 'flatrate' && $quote->getSubtotal() >= 15) continue;
```

Adjust `flatrate` and `15` as required.

Answer (score 1):

Create a module and register an observer for the sales_quote_address_collect_totals_after event:

```
public function hideFlatRate1($observer)
{
    $quoteAddress = $observer->getQuoteAddress();
    $quote = $quoteAddress->getQuote();
    $total = $quote->getGrandTotal();

    if ($total < 15){
        $store = Mage::app()->getStore($quote->getStoreId());
        $storeId = $store->getId();
        $store->setConfig('carriers/flat_rate1/active', 0);
    }

}
```

Basically this observer is notified when the sales_quote_address_collect_totals_after event is dispatched in the collectTotals method, line 1009 of Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address. On the one page checkout, when you submit your shipping address, this method is called to get the shipping rates for your shipping address.